# Combining conditional and non-conditional classes in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to set a class using vue the value in a vue param. Additionally, I need to conditionally set a class based on if a vue param is a certain value. Is it possible to combine the two below functionalities in to one class assignment?

```
<button :class="'btn btn-primary modal modal-' + modal.id" 
        :class="{'modal-active' : modal.active}">
</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it as follows by using an array :

```
   <div v-bind:class="[{'modal-active' : modal.active}, 'btn btn-primary modal modal-' + modal.id]"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more modern approach would be using the [`computed`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) property to construct an array of class names:

```
<template>
  <button :class="classNames"></button>
</template>

<script setup>
const classNames = computed(() => ['btn', 'btn-primary', 'modal', `modal-${model.id}`, modal.active && 'modal-active']);
</script>
```